# XMLHttpRequest on java

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest

I need to convert the following Javascript pseudo-class to Java code. I'm googling information about XMLHttpRequest (or equivalent) in Java and i'm confused:

```
function conexionSOAP(url, uri) {
// Constructor
this.uri = 'urn:' + uri;
this.url = url;
this.cabeceraXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
        + '<soap:Envelope '
        + 'soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" '
        + 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '
        + 'xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" '
        + 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '
        + 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
        + '<soap:Body>' + '<';
this.sessionKey = null;

// Metodos
var self = this;

(...)

this.llamar_metodo = function(metodo, argumentos, http, loadCallback,
        errorCallback) {
    // Función que transforma las llamadas a métodos en requests XML
    var XMLmsg = self.cabeceraXML + metodo + ' xmlns="' + self.uri + '"';
    if (argumentos == null) {
        XMLmsg = XMLmsg + ' xsi:nil="true" />';
    } else {
        var i, I;
        XMLmsg = XMLmsg + '>';
        for (i = 0, I = argumentos.length; i < I; i++) {
            var tipo = typeof argumentos[i];
            if (tipo == "number") {
                if (argumentos[i] % 1) {
                    tipo = "float";
                } else {
                    tipo = "int";
                }
            }
            XMLmsg = XMLmsg + '<c-gensym' + (2 * (i + 2))
                    + ' xsi:type="xsd:' + tipo + '">' +   argumentos[i]
                    + '</c-gensym' + (2 * (i + 2)) + '>';
        }
        XMLmsg = XMLmsg + '</' + metodo + '>';
    }
    XMLmsg = XMLmsg + '</soap:Body>' + '</soap:Envelope>';
    // Una vez preparado el XML preparamos el HttpRequest

    http.open("POST", self.url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
    http.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'ParkingClientJS');
    http
            .setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '"' + self.uri + '#' + metodo
                    + '"');
    http.timeout = 15000;
    http.onload = loadCallback;
    http.onerror = errorCallback;
    http.ontimeout = errorCallback;
    http.send(XMLmsg);
};

function readyState(metodo, http) {     
    var respuesta = null;
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        if (http.status == 200) {
            var responseTag = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName(metodo
                    + 'Response');
            if (responseTag) {
                if (responseTag[0].childNodes.length <= 1) {
                    respuesta = responseTag[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
                } else {
                    var i, I;
                    respuesta = [];
                    for (i = 0, I = responseTag[0].childNodes.length; i < I; i++) {
                        respuesta
                                .push(responseTag[0].childNodes[i].textContent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            respuesta = "--EE--";
        }
    }
    return respuesta;
}

function error_timeOut(http) {
    var respuesta = "--EE--";
    http.abort();
    return respuesta;
}
}
```

Specifically, How must I implement the method `llamar_metodo`? Notice that the XMLHttpRequest is passed to this method (`http` parameter) and the request must be async. There are auxiliar methods like this:

```
function(method, [param1, param2, ...], responseCallback){
     var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
     self.llamar_metodo(method, [ param1, param2, ... ], http, function() {
        var response = readyState(metodo, http);
        responseCallback(response)
    }, function() {
        var respuesta = error_timeOut(http);
        responseCallback(response)
    });
}
```

Finally, the implementation must be android-compatible.

Thanks for your help I'm really confused with the Http stuff.

Sorry for my english